# Solving 2D reaction-diffusion equation using Crank-Nicolson

Tags: r, numerical-methods, pde

I'm trying to solve following system of PDEs to simulate a pattern formation process in two dimensions.

dU/dt = KU<sup>2</sup>V - k<sub>1</sub>U + D<sub>U</sub>∇<sup>2</sup>U

dV/dt = α - KU<sup>2</sup>V - k<sub>2</sub>V + D<sub>V</sub>∇<sup>2</sup>V

The boundary conditions are for both (U and V) are 0 at the right, left and upper boundary. For the bottom boundary, U has a fixed concentration of 65 and V has zero-flux (dV/dy = 0).

I've tried to implement it in R and it is more or less working, as long as the length of grid is 1 for x- and y-direction. As soon as I'm changing Lx and Ly the whole thing is not working anymore. But, for my underlying model I need to solve it for Lx=262 and Ly=150.

I'm quite new in this stuff and I'm kind of suspecting that I probably misunderstand something and can't figure out what it is.

**Edit (10/25/2017):**

I missed to add that there is a reason for not using packages like ReacTran or deSolve. I'm aware of their existence and using ReacTran to check the result of my code. But, I need to understand the algorithm itself to implement it later in a larger simulation project that should simulate the evolution of "populations" of patterns.

The comment tdma in the code means Tridiagonal matrix algorithm.

**Code in R:**

```
library(igraph)
library(raster)
library(pheatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)

#Model: Connahs et al 2017 - Gray Scott Model: Butterfly eyespots
#Numerical algorithm: Crank Nicolson - ADI


#A1 -> reaction term: K*A1^2*A2-k1*A1
fu <- function(K, U, V, k1){
  X<-U
  for(i in 2:(nrow(U)-1)){
    for(j in 2:(ncol(U)-1)){
      X[i,j]<-dt*(K*(U[i,j]^2)*V[i,j] - k1*U[i,j])
    }
  }
  return(X)
}

#A2 -> reaction term: alpha-K*A1^2*A2-k2*A2
fv <- function(alpha, K, U, V, k2){
  Y<-V
  for(i in 2:(nrow(V)-1)){
    for(j in 2:(ncol(V)-1)){
      Y[i,j]<-dt*(alpha-K*(U[i,j]^2)*V[i,j]-k2*V[i,j])
    }
  }
  return(Y)
}

#Diffusion solver
CN<-function(Nx,Ny,dx,dy,dt,t,D,f,C,C2,M){
  S <- matrix(0,Nx,Ny)
  P <- matrix(0,Nx,Ny)
  Z <- matrix(0,Nx,Ny)

  bx <- 0.5*(D*dt/(dx^2))
  by <- 0.5*(D*dt/(dy^2))

  U<-C
  V<-C2

  if(M == 1){
    f <- fu(K, U, V, k1)
  }
  else if(M == 2){
    f <- fv(alpha, K, V, U, k2)
  }

  for(j in 2:(Ny-1)){
    for(i in 1:Nx){
      S[i,j]<-U[i,j]+by*(U[i,j+1]-2*U[i,j]+U[i,j-1])
    }
  }

  for(j in 2:(Ny-1)){
    for(i in 2:(Nx-1)){
      P[i,j]<-S[i,j]+bx*(S[i+1,j]-2*S[i,j]+S[i-1,j])+0.5*dt*f[i,j]
    }
  }

  for(j in 2:(Ny-1)){
    a<-NULL
    b<-NULL
    c<-NULL
    r<-NULL
    q<-NULL
    for(i in 2:Nx-1){
      a[i]<- -bx
      b[i]<- 1+2*bx
      c[i]<- -bx
      r[i]<- P[i,j]
    }

    #Boundary 
    ua <- U[1,j] - by*(U[1,j+1]-2*U[1,j]+U[1,j-1])
    ub <- U[Nx,j] - by*(U[Nx,j+1] - 2*U[Nx,j] + U[Nx,j-1])

    r[2] <- r[2] - a[2] * ua
    r[Nx-1] <- r[Nx-1] - c[Nx-1] * ub

    #tdma
    for(i in 2:(Nx-1)){
      b[i]<-b[i]-a[i]/b[i-1]*c[i-1]
      r[i]<-r[i]-a[i]/b[i-1]*r[i-1]
    }

    q[Nx-1]<-r[Nx-1]/b[Nx-1]
    for(i in seq(Nx-2,1,-1)){
      q[i]<-(r[i]-c[i]*q[i+1])/b[i]
    }

    for(i in 2:(Nx-1)){
      Z[i,j]<-q[i]
    }
    #Boundary - useless?
    if(M==2){
      Z[1,j]<-Z[2,j]
      Z[Nx,j]<-ub
    }
    else{
      Z[1,j]<-ua
      Z[Nx,j]<-ub
    }

  }## X end

  for(j in 2:(Nx-1)){
    a<-NULL
    b<-NULL
    c<-NULL
    r<-NULL
    q<-NULL
    for(i in 2:Ny-1){
      a[i]<- -by
      b[i]<- 1+2*by
      c[i]<- -by
      r[i]<- Z[j,i]
    }

    ua <- U[j,1]
    ub <- U[j,Ny]

    r[2] <- r[2] - a[2] * ua
    r[Ny-1] <- r[Ny-1] - c[Ny-1] * ub

    #tdma
    for(i in 2:(Ny-1)){
      b[i]<-b[i]-a[i]/b[i-1]*c[i-1]
      r[i]<-r[i]-a[i]/b[i-1]*r[i-1]
    }

    q[Ny-1]<-r[Ny-1]/b[Ny-1]
    for(i in seq(Ny-2,1,-1)){
      q[i]<-(r[i]-c[i]*q[i+1])/b[i]
    }

    for(i in 2:(Ny-1)){
      U[j,i]<-q[i]
    }
  }

  if(M==2){
    U[Nx,]<-U[Nx-1,]
  }
  return(U)

}##end CN

#grid points
Nx <- 105
Ny <- 60

#length (in micrometer)
Lx <- 1
Ly <- 1

x0 <- 0
xL <- Lx
y0 <- 0
yL <- Ly

#spatial steps
dx <- (xL-x0)/(Nx-1)
dy <- (yL-y0)/(Ny-1)

#time steps
Tmax <- 144
dt <- 0.0005
nt <- Tmax/dt
t<-0

#Diffusion constants
Du <- 0.01
Dv <- 0.12

#init - A1 = U; A2 = V
U<-matrix(0,Nx,Ny)
U[Nx,]<-65
V<-matrix(0,Nx,Ny)

#reaction parameter
alpha <- (5.5*10^-3)
K <- 2.22*10^-7
k1 <- 0.1*10^-3
k2 <- 0.08*10^-3   


while(t<Tmax){

  if(t==60){
    alpha<-alpha*0.75
  }

  du <- CN(Nx,Ny,dx,dy,dt,t,Du,f_u,U,V,1)
  dv <- CN(Nx,Ny,dx,dy,dt,t,Dv,f_v,V,U,2)

  print(t)

  U<-du
  V<-dv

  t <- t+dt
}

pheatmap(V, cluster_row = FALSE, cluster_col = FALSE, color= brewer.pal(5, "YlGnBu"),border_color = NA)
```

Comment: Just a comment: ever tried solving it with `deSolve` in R? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/vignettes/deSolve.pdf

Comment: Yes, but this is actually not an option, because I need to understand the algorithm. I have to add this to another bigger simulation project in C++.

Comment: I think you're reinventing the wheel. The [`ReacTran`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReacTran/index.html) package has a slew of useful functions for setting up and solving models exactly like this. I'd suggest reading the vignettes for that package – e.g., section 5 of [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReacTran/vignettes/ReacTran.pdf). Their [book](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781402086236) provides a  more thorough discussion. Is this code translated directly from another language? The heavy use of `for` loops will be slow in R, as well as being really verbose.

Comment: Solutions like this are commonly done with finite element methods.  Looks like you're using finite differences on a regular grid.  I wouldn't think to do it in R.

Comment: C-N is an implicit time integration scheme; that means you have to do a matrix inversion and iteration.  Where's that in your code?

Comment: The part of the code is commented with tdma. It is the Tridiagonal matrix algorithm. Or do I miss something here?